# Defining a parameterised Fixpoint in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to define a fixpoint in Coq in which one of the function definitions refers to the other through a parameter, but I'm getting some confusing errors.

I've minimised the definition to this:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Notations.
Require Import Coq.Init.Datatypes.

Inductive Wrapper (T : Type) :=
  | Wrap : T -> Wrapper T
  .
Inductive Unwrapper :=
  | Empty : Unwrapper
  | Unwrap : Wrapper Unwrapper -> Unwrapper
  .

Fixpoint Unwrapper_size (u : Unwrapper) {struct u} : nat :=
  match u with
  | Empty => O
  | Unwrap w => Wrapper_size w
  end

with Wrapper_size (w : Wrapper Unwrapper) {struct w} : nat :=
  match w with
  | Wrap _ t => Unwrapper_size t
  end.
```

which results in this error:

```
Recursive definition of Wrapper_size is ill-formed.
In environment
Unwrapper_size : Unwrapper -> nat
Wrapper_size : Wrapper Unwrapper -> nat
w : Wrapper Unwrapper
t : Unwrapper
Recursive call to Unwrapper_size has principal argument equal to
"t" instead of a subterm of "w".
Recursive definition is:
"fun w : Wrapper Unwrapper =>
match w with
| Wrap _ t => Unwrapper_size t
end".
```

Here, `t` is evidently a subterm of `w` — `w` was what we're matching on to get `t`, but Coq doesn't accept it. What's the mistake here, and how can I get around it?

Comment: Your code is very suspicious: The only base case returns 0 and there is no operation on nat. So that if it terminates it only return 0. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I've minimised the definition to make it clearer to read. My actual use-case is less vacuous, but it just adds more noise to the problem. (You could imagine actually incrementing the results of the recursive calls to make a more useful function.)

Comment: As somebody said on IRC, for the current example, "try defining wrapper and unwrapper as mutually inductive", giving `Inductive Wrapper := Wrap: Unwrapper -> Wrapper with Unwrapper`: Coq's concept of "subterm" assumes your recursion follows the structure of your datatypes. I suppose that won't help for the original one, but it'd be good to have an example where this doesn't work. I do have another idea tho...

Comment: If you also wrap other things, then you need to break the mutual recursion and make functions "parallel" to datatype. So write `Wrapper_size: Wrapper T -> (T -> nat) -> nat.` Then I'd try using `Wrapper_size Unwrapper_size` in `Unwrapper_size`: Coq might do enough inlining in termination checking to recognize this is safe. (In this example it's also easy to do that inlining by hand: Unwrapper_size` would match on `Unwrap (wrap t)` and recurse on `t`).

Comment: If all else fails there's always well-founded induction, but it's annoying enough that I'd try avoiding it.

Comment: For the future reference, let me link the corresponding [issue #9045](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9045) on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you use `Wrapper` also on other arguments. Then you need to break the mutual recursion and make functions "parallel" to datatype. So you want to write `Wrapper_size: Wrapper T -> (T -> nat) -> nat`.

Then you can use `Wrapper_size Unwrapper_size` in `Unwrapper_size`: Coq should do enough inlining in termination checking to recognize this is safe.

In this example it's also easy to do that inlining by hand: `Unwrapper_size` would match on `Unwrap (Wrap _ t)` and recurse on `t`.